# Getting a "You have files awaiting to be copied onto your disc" message on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, taskbar, optical-drive

Upon logging into my computer, I sometimes receive a message that says something like "You have files awaiting to be copied onto your disc" above the taskbar near the clock. I have Windows 7 and did copy files awhile back onto a DVD but not recently. How would I get rid of this message?

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/654-you-have-files-waiting-burned-disc-stop-message.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1: From Computer**

Right click on the DVD Drive in Computer and click "Delete Temporary Files"

**Option 2: Clear Temporary Burn Folder**

Delete the contents of the folder below.  Warning: Don't delete the folder itself.
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Temporary Burn Folder

For more details, read the article [You have files waiting to be burned to disc - Stop Message - Windows 7 Help Forums](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/654-you-have-files-waiting-burned-disc-stop-message.html).